# C# Web API - Error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with a controller in Web API application.

In that controller, there is a method.

1. When I set the return type of that method to bool, it works on local host, but it doesn't work on server. If I set the return type to string, everything works fine.
2. When I use webclient to download something (even everything is inside try-catch block so it shouldn't fail), on localhost it works just fine, on server it does not.

In both case, server throw 404 error to any method - whole API does not work.

It has to be something with IIS settings on the server, but I don't know what could cause this.

Comment: Most likely it is a problem with your routes or at least how you perceive the routes to exist on the server. Are you sure both api routes start at `/api/{controller}`?

Comment: First case is about setting return type... second case is about body of the method.... if I set the return type to string and the body of the method to 'return "hello"' it works ok... I think if the problem is with routes, it would throw 404 even in this case...

Comment: Show us some code, which url you are accessing an so on. Must people treat WebAPI like MVC and add the method name to the url which is bad. eg. Use http://hostname/api/{controller}/1 to fetch controller item with id 1 ..  most people try /api/{controller}/Method/id, which is bad.